# MVC C# Using statement throwing System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, oracle19c

My application built with C#, ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework (v6.4.4) - code-first approach and an Oracle database.

I have an action that works fine, but once in a while it fails and saying

> Object reference not set to an instance of an Object

Exception is shown at using statement line number*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestInfo()
{
    try
    {
        using (TestConnection db = new TestConnection())
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex.ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
    }
}

public partial class TestConnection : DbContext
{
   public TestConnection() : base("name=TestConnection")
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#remarks *"The name can also be passed in the form "name=myname", in which case the name must be found in the config file or an exception will be thrown."* So what do you have in your config file? The full stack trace would be useful also.